# Order of prints with string concatenation

Tags: java, string-concatenation, operator-precedence

Why does the following code print

```
float called long called 20.0 21
```

instead of

```
float called 20.0 long called 21
```

Here's the code:

```
public class Test5 {
    static float fun(int a) {
        System.out.print("float called ");
        return a;
    }

    static long fun(long a) {
        System.out.print("long called ");
        return a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(fun(20) + " " + fun(21L));
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't return the `String` "float called #" you print `float called` and return the #. Likewise with `long called`.... So print msg 1. Print msg 2. Then print msg 3. Not print one msg. Also, you are calling your `float` function with an `int`.

Comment: It would be good if you explain with which part you have difficulties. It's very unclear for which part you want an explanation. Is it method overloading? Is it how a `main` works? Is it how `println` works? Or maybe why it outputs a float with a decimal point? Or what `21l` means (btw. please use upper-case `L`, looks like `1` else)? Or maybe what `+` means on strings? Or how `+` works when used with numbers and strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`System.out.println(fun(20)+" "+fun(21l));` is passed a `String` that is the result of concatenating the values returned by `fun(20)` and `fun(21l)`. Therefore, these two methods are executed before this `println` statement, each of them printing its own `String`.

- first `fun(20)` prints "float called " and returns 20.0
- then `fun(21l)` prints "long called " and returns 21
- finally `System.out.println(fun(20)+" "+fun(21l));` prints "20.0 21"

Answer (score -1):

This is an example of method overloading. The example shows that an class can have several methods with the same name.

Some more examples are listed here:
https://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/method-overloading/

Comment: It would be great if you include some of the examples here. An answer should be self-contained, without the need of looking somewhere else. It's good to have external links as references, but only for an interested reader that wants to read more about it. Not as essential thing needed to understand the answer or the term *method overloading*.